# cmake SHARED lib led to clang: error: linker command failed

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, lib, vcpkg

On macOS I'm trying to build my own small library based on `fmt`, while installing it with `vcpkg` and building the project with `cmake`.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

project(MYLIB)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED)

include_directories(~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include)

add_library(mylib mylib.cpp)
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"

#include <fmt/core.h>

float add(float a, float b)
{
    fmt::print("Hello MYLIB, world!\n");
    return (a + b);
}
```

With the above I can build the static flavor of it. But it fails while trying to build the SHARED version with

```
add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp)
```

which led to:

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro build % rm -Rf *
zsh: sure you want to delete all 4 files in /Users/user/mylib/build [yn]? y
user@users-MacBook-Pro build % cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/user/mylib/build
user@users-MacBook-Pro build % make    
Scanning dependencies of target mylib
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libmylib.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "fmt::v8::vprint(fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v8::basic_format_args<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >)", referenced from:
      add(float, float) in mylib.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libmylib.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You should either `#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY` or explicitly link against fmt `target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE fmt::fmt)`

Comment: It seems to work with `link_libraries(fmt::fmt)`, not sure why?

Comment: `fmt::fmt` is an exported target therefore it has `INTERFACE` properties with include paths and required library files already set. This is basically how cmake works.